# Finding character position using indexOf

Tags: java, string, indexof

Using indexOf how can I find the character position of the first "l" in the string of the variable x

```
x = "hello"
```

Comment: By looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)).

Answer (score 0):

`Use x.indexOf("l");`, with "l" being the character to search for. **This method returns the first occurence of the character.**

Take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) for more info.

Comment: Their are two l's though, will that method work to find the position of the 1st or the 2nd "l"

Comment: @Drax you clearly didn't read the link: "Returns the index within this string of the **first occurrence** of the specified character or -1 if the character does not occur."

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the following code snippet would work

`int firstOccurrence = x.indexOf("l");`

If you want to specify a custom starting point take a look at `indexOf(String ch, int fromIndex) method`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29